# Adding elements to sides of centered element without changing alignment

Tags: css, centering

I have a dynamically created header on a page. Sometimes, there are left and right buttons to the sides of it, sometimes only left or right, and sometimes none.

Is there a way to center the main text and keep it centered when adding other elements next to it? Currently, when I add the left/right buttons, the whole assembly is centered. If I only add one button, the whole thing is shifted off to one side.

**How do I keep the main element centered but add other elements around it?**

---

This works fine:

```
<h1>
  <img src="left.png" />
  Main Title
  <img src="right.png" />
</h1>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<h1>
  <img src="left.png" />
  Main Title
</h1>
```

Comment: It's not a nice coding put an img inside an `<h1>`. Anyway, do you know something about css?

Comment: @maurelio79 Yeah, I know how to center elements and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered an answer to my question incase anyone in the future finds this post.

Keep the element in the markup (HTML), but style it using CSS to `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. This keeps the formatting on the page, but doesn't render the object to view.

**`visibility: hidden`** NOT `display: none`

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone) article for more information...

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #header {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
        line-height: 53px;
    }

    .left {
        position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
    }

    .right {
        position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<img class="left" src="http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-icons/user-icons-by-2shi/png/48/user1.png" />
<h1>My Title</h1>
<img class="right" src="http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-icons/user-icons-by-2shi/png/48/user1.png" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But you can find many more. Try to remove right or left img and title should remain centered.

P.S.
If you don't want a fixed header, change `#header` to

```
#header {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
```